# autoregressive models in R with dynlm function

Tags: r

I have a question in R on the dynlm function.

I have a model that looks like this:

[image]

The Y (*U*) variable here is the change in unemployment from t - 1 to t. The X variable here is jobless claims.

I need to write a code for the model ADL(1,3) with dynlm function.

I have written a code like this:

reg1<- dynlm(diff(unemp)~L(diff(unemp),1)+L(claims, 0:3), data=data)

I have one doubt: should it be claims(0:3) or claims(0:2)?

Comment: you can use `summary(reg1)` to see the difference.

Comment: @AlexB I see four coefficients instead of 3